# How to reject symbols in application.inputbox

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

I have some code below that creates an input box, and I don't want to allow people to type symbols in. Is there something I can do to have a msgBox popup when someone enters a symbol that says not to, or disallow them altogether? Code pasted below. Thanks for any help up front :)

```
If AnswerYes = vbYes Then

Dim Discount1 As Variant
Discount1 = Application.InputBox("DO NOT ENTER % SIGN", "Product Discount Percentage", "##", Type:=1)

Dim Discount2 As Variant
Discount2 = Application.InputBox("DO NOT ENTER % SIGN", "SNS Discount net Percentage", "##", Type:=1)
```

Comment: The best thing in this case is to create a userform (that might look exactly like the input box if you want), and capture the `Textbox_Change` event. In that event code, check the key and only allow the acceptable keystroke to be displayed and ignore everything else. Take a look at [this video](https://youtu.be/FQez_sbcSNk) for a little more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. The `False` response is for `cancel`. It will reject any text that isn't numeric. If you wanted something more sophisticated consider using ascii code.

```
Sub makeInput()
makeEntry:
    theResponse = Application.InputBox("DO NOT ENTER % SIGN", "Product Discount Percentage", "##", Type:=1)
    
    If theResponse = False Then Exit Sub

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(theResponse)
        If Not (IsNumeric(Mid(theResponse, i, 1))) Then
            MsgBox "Invalid Entry"
            GoTo makeEntry
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a userform like this

[image]

And then paste this code in the userform code area. The `TextBox1_KeyPress` will ensure the user doesn't type anything other than numbers and decimal.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    MyValue = 0: Cancelled = False
End Sub

'~~> OK Button
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Len(Trim(TextBox1.Text)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox Label1.Caption
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    MyValue = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    Unload Me
End Sub

'~~> CANCEL Button
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Unload Me
    Cancelled = True
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case vbKey0 To vbKey9, vbKeyBack, vbKeyClear, vbKeyDelete, vbKeyLeft, vbKeyRight, vbKeyUp, vbKeyDown, vbKeyTab
            If KeyAscii = 46 Then If InStr(1, TextBox1.Text, ".") Then KeyAscii = 0
        Case Else
            KeyAscii = 0
            Beep
    End Select
End Sub
```

Now you can use it like this. Paste this code in a module

```
Option Explicit

Public MyValue As Double
Public Cancelled As Boolean

Sub Sample()
    Dim frm As New UserForm1
    Dim Discount1 As Double
    Dim Discount2 As Double

    With frm
        .Caption = "WhatEver Title"
        .Label1.Caption = "Enter Product Discount Percentage"
        .Show
    End With
    
    If Cancelled = False Then
        Discount1 = MyValue
        MsgBox Discount1
    End If
    
    Set frm = New UserForm1
    
    With frm
        .Caption = "WhatEver Title"
        .Label1.Caption = "Enter SNS Discount net Percentage"
        .Show
    End With
    
    If Cancelled = False Then
        Discount2 = MyValue
        MsgBox Discount2
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

---

**EDIT**

If you want, you can create a common function for the module code.

```
Option Explicit

Public MyValue As Double
Public Cancelled As Boolean

Sub Sample()
    Dim Discount1 As Double
    Dim Discount2 As Double

    Discount1 = ShowInputBox("WhatEver Title", "Enter Product Discount Percentage")
    
    If Cancelled = False Then MsgBox Discount1
    
    Discount2 = ShowInputBox("WhatEver Title", "Enter SNS Discount net Percentage")
    
    If Cancelled = False Then MsgBox Discount2
End Sub

Private Function ShowInputBox(Title As String, Msg As String) As Double
    Dim frm As New UserForm1

    With frm
        .Caption = Title
        .Label1.Caption = Msg
        .Show
    End With
    
    If Cancelled = False Then ShowInputBox = MyValue
End Function
```